# SEO Impact of moving blog posts from root to subdirectory /blog

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

In a current corporate WordPress site, I have all the pages (about us, services, etc...) in root, but also the blog posts. For example: domain.com/a-simple-service-page, but also  domain.com/a-simple-blog-post. Right now, blog articles receive quite a few visits daily.

I plan to move the blog posts from root to the subdirectory /blog, like this: domain.com/blog/a-simple-blog-post

Two questions:

- It is advisable, from an SEO point of view, to move blog posts from root to the subdirectory /blog and keep the pages in the root?
- If it is correct to do so, should this affect in SEO results?

Comment: SEO doesn't care what the internal structure of the website is.  What matters is what is seen by the world, which can be altered using rewrites.  Are these pages already indexed well ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, they are well indexed. So, should i move blog posts to subdirectory /blog or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely fine to do this. Just make sure that each of the old blog URLs properly 301-redirect to the corresponding new URL, and you should have no issues. [According to Google Analyst Gary Illyes](https://twitter.com/methode/status/757923179641839616) and Google's own [site move documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/site-move-with-url-changes), 301 redirects do not themselves cause any negative SEO impact.

Comment: In terms of SEO, should I move these blog posts to subdirectory /blog or is it not necessary?

Comment: Strictly in terms of SEO, I don't believe you would get any positive boost from it either.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I would always try to avoid unnecessary redirects, especially when it comes to pure cosmetics on the URLs. What's wrong with leaving the blog URLs in the root?

If this also requires changes to the internal linking and the blog moves down one level in click depth, there may also be an inpact on rankings and/or traffic, unless you adjust the link structures.

You can still make a blog folder (/blog) and leave the URLs in the root. The advantage of this is (like with product-urls in a shop) that you can list the articles in several subdirectories without generating duplicate content. The hierarchical logic can be shown wonderfully via the breadcrumbs.

- domain.com/blog

  - domain.com/blog-post-1
  - domain.com/blog-post-2
  - domain.com/blog-post-3
- domain.com/blog/category

  - domain.com/blog-post-1
  - domain.com/blog-post-3

Answer (score 0):

I  would restructure your files to use the subfolder anyway. This helps with maintenance and growth. I  would further categorise them (if it applies to you) into nested folders.

Then its a choice between 3 alternatives, to expose it to the world.

- example.com
- example.com/blog
- example.com/blog/category

I would suggest option 2 for publishing. My site is tiny, but I  have found no impacts from using 301s to redirect. And the sooner you do it, the better it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, if you do the redirects and keep the redirection from old to new post for about a year. There will be impact for sure on already indexed and cached websites.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this change does not have much effect on your website's SEO ranking. You are simply adding a depth to the crawl depth.
Of course, be careful that if you do this now, make sure to change the 301 redirects.